# I'm getting cmake error while installing termuxa opencv

Tags: python, android, numpy, opencv, cmake

```
CMake Error at cmake/android/OpenCVDetectAndroidSDK.cmake:49 (message):
  Android SDK: specify path to Android SDK via ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /
  ANDROID_HOME / ANDROID_SDK variables
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/android/OpenCVDetectAndroidSDK.cmake:172 (ocv_detect_android_sdk)
  CMakeLists.txt:761 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I will install opencv on termux, but I get such an error, how can I solve it during configuration?

If my configuration is

```
LDFLAGS=" -llog -lpython3" cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX -DBUILD_opencv_python3=on -DBUILD_opencv_python2=off -DWITH_QT=OFF -DWITH_GTK=OFF ..
```

Comment: well it did not find the andoid sdk, period.

Comment: The error message clearly tells about variables `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_HOME`, `ANDROID_SDK`. Do you have **any** of these variables set in your environment? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html

Comment: also, to build the opencv android sdk, you should use https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/platforms/android , not cmake directly

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-do-i-download-opencv-to-termux/10237